# Decimal Truncation/Rounding difference in console and though JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, t-sql, jdbc, rounding-error

I have an issue while inserting a double value into a database table with some decimal precision. I am using MS SQL Server version 10.0.4000
Below is a sample table with decimal column having 4 decimal places.

```
create table test (
test decimal (18,4))
```

When I insert the value “36.78675” through the MSSQL console, it gets rounded as `36.7868` as the field is of 4 decimals only. This is fine.

```
DECLARE @T DECIMAL(18, 5)

SET @T = 36.78675

insert into test values(@T)

select * from test
```

But when I execute equivalent insert (using prepared statement) through my java code (MS SQL JDBC driver), the data gets stored in the table is `36.7867`. If I have a value like `36.786750001`, both console and the JDBC rounds to `36.7868`. 
The java object I use is double. I am calling setDouble() with double value. Here it automatically picks the data type. But there is another JDBC method which takes object and the data type. Using this, I tested with DECIMAL  and FLOAT type. All are giving same result. I even changed the jdbc driver to I-net. There also same result.

Anybody know why the rounding works differently through the driver? Is there any setting to make it behave like the console?

Comment: Saying "SQL Server console", do you mean SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 5):

It's because of the nature of binary floating point, which is what you're using with `double` (in Java).

The *exact* value of the `double` closest to 36.7875 is

```
36.7867499999999978399500832892954349517822265625
```

That would be rounded down to 36.7867. Whereas the *exact* value of the `double` closest to 36.78750001 is

```
36.786750000099999624580959789454936981201171875
```

That would be rounded up to 36.7878. That's why you're getting this behaviour. The console is presumably treating the input *as a decimal number* rather than converting to binary floating point at all.

If exact decimal digits are important to you, you probably shouldn't be using a binary floating point type - use `BigDecimal` instead.

You should really think about what your value represents. If it's a physical continuous value such as height, length or weight, then using `double` is probably appropriate after all - but you shouldn't get hung-up about cases like this. If it's an *artificial* construct with discrete (decimal-based) values, such as monetary values, then you should definitely use `BigDecimal`, or simply scale an integer.

Comment: Thanks for the details. More than the percision, my issue is the inconsistency in the java rouding and the database's default truncation/rounding. Java rounding gives 36.7868 when the value is "36.78675" but the stored value in the datatbase is "36.7867" if do not specifically round the value before storing. I need to do retrival of the data and do a comparison to the value in the java code. Here I will not get a match as I cam comparing 36.7868 (java code ) against 36.7867 (databse).

Comment: @BijuSanakan: My point is that the value of a `double` variable *cannot* be 36.78675. It's just not possible. It's like trying to write down the exact value of "one third" in a decimal representation. Again, if the exact value of "36.78675" is important to you, you should use `BigDecimal`.

Comment: I agree with you. 
But my question is why it is differently rounding in java and mssql for the same number 36.78675.



public static void roundUnits(double v1)
{ 
  
  return java.util.Math.round(v1 * 10000)/10000;

}




double d = 36.78675;

System.out.println( roundUnits(d));





When I am calling the above code, it prints out 36.7868.

I am expecting the same behaviour from the MSSQL. But in MSSQL it is getting stored as 36.7867

Comment: @BijuSanakan: Because presumably the SQL Server console isn't converting it to a `double` first. It's treating it *just* as decimal input. In your `roundUnits` method, you're multiplying and dividing by 10000 which could be affecting the data in all kinds of ways - you'd have to look at *exactly* what the results are with your sample input to understand it. But the fundamental difference here is whether you start with 36.78675 (if you use a decimal-based representation) or 36.7867499999999978399500832892954349517822265625 (if you use a 64-bit binary floating point representation).